# Logging out user from application FB.logout() not facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read Facebook documentation and it says that `FB.logout` is used to log the user out of both web application and Facebook. I have made a website on which I use `FB.logout()` but I want only the session of the user to be revoked not log the user out of the Faceboook.
I have seen this thing been done on many other websites looking at their code I find they are also using code like

```
function fb_logout(){
            FB.logout(function(response) {
            console.log('loggedout');
            });
        }
```

I also tried using this function but I still log my users out of Facebook too.
Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Yes, by clearing the cookies FB has set under your domain. Btw., Platform Policies _require_ you to offer the user the possibility to log out of your site and Facebook at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete all the data you have on user and show them login button again (mimicking logout from your app) without calling "FB.logout" function(it logs user out of facebook too). This will behave as per your needs, once user clicks on the login button again, you will again get the data without him needing to login to facebook again.